# How to change value of a property 'SelectedValue' of 'ListPicker' control programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two 'ListPicker' controls. How could I make it so that after user changes 'SelectedValue' property of one of these controls a corresponding property of a second control would also change?

Can someone please provide us a example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean whatever you select on ListPicker A then the SelectedValue of ListPicker B should be the same or do you want to do a cascading ListPicker that depends on one control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set select item like this code.when you fill list at the time you can set selected item property.

```
 private void FillAssetType(int assetTypeID)
        {
            List<TbAssetType> lst = Asset.GetAssetType();
            TbAssetType tb = new TbAssetType { AssetTypeName = "Select Asset Type" };
            lst.Insert(0, tb);
            lstpickAssetType.ItemsSource = lst;
            lstpickAssetType.SelectedItem = lst.Where(p => p.AssetTypeID == assetTypeID).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```